# fetch_page returns no cursor and more = false prematurely

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to chunk the results of a big db request by using gae cursors.
The test involves inserting a random number between 75 and 300 of an entity, and then attempting to pull it out in chunks of 50 using fetch page.

```
def get(self):
    num_entries = self.request.get(NUM_ENTRIES)
    if not num_entries:
        num_entries = CHUNK_SIZE

    req_cursor = self.request.get(CURSOR)
    cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=req_cursor)
    query_tuple = Animal.query().fetch_page(num_entries, start_cursor=cursor)

    (animals, next_cursor, more) = query_tuple
    if next_cursor:
        next_cursor = next_cursor.urlsafe()

    self.response.write(json.dumps({
        ANIMALS: [animal.to_dict() for animal in animals],
        CURSOR: next_cursor,
        MORE: more
    }))
```

where CHUNK_SIZE is 50. However, the test continually fails because fetch_page returns 'more' as false wayyy before there are no entries left in the query, and returns 'cursor' as None if ever there are less than 50 entries left in the query. I don't understand. Based on the method description, neither of these things should happen.

Fetch_page is said to return 'at most' as many entries as specified, which means to me it should try to get as many as are left. More is supposed to never return a false negative, since it is based on probably_has_next, described here:

> Like has_next(), but uses a faster (and sometimes inaccurate) shortcut.
>
> May return a false positive (True when next() would actually raise StopIteration), but never a
> false negative (False when next() would actually return a result).

If this is how they actually behave, it doesn't appear to me that these methods can be relied on. Please help. Thanks!

EDIT: Thought it might be a consistency issue, so I slept (on my local machine) for 30 seconds after the post. Despite that, I'm still having the same issue, even when only posting 40 entities.

Comment: You need to post how you insert the data. FYI your code won't work if the request passed in NUM_ENTRIES, since it's a string, and you never cast it to int.

Comment: Are you testing on the dev server or in production.  You do need to take into account eventual consistency.  How much time are you leaving between creating the entities and running the query.

Comment: the data insertion is constructing an object with four fields and calling .put(). I think @TimHoffman is/was correct; seems like an eventual consistency problem. Just a very extreme one since I'm inserting so many elements.

Comment: @marcadian I now cast num_entries to an int in a helper function. thanks